# Adding class is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hi i am creating a table dynamically in jquery. What i am doing over here is also adding class which is "draggable ui-widget" but it is not affecting/working on my table.

```
   var tab_title = $tab_title_input.val() || 'Tab '+tab_counter;
        //alert(tab_title);
        $tabs.tabs('add', '#tabs-'+tab_counter, tab_title);                 

        var newTableDiv = $("<div />",{id: 'dialog'+tab_counter});          
        newTableDiv.appendTo("body");           
        alert("div appended to body"+" "+'dialog'+tab_counter);
        //var newTable = $('<table id="myTable'+tab_counter+'" class="draggable" ></table>');
********************Class which i am adding in table but not working***********
        var newTable = $("<table />",{"class": "draggable ui-widget",id: 'myTable'+tab_counter,width: '100%',border: '0',cellspacing: '1px',cellpadding: '2px'});                       
        newTable.appendTo('#dialog'+tab_counter);           
        alert('myTable'+tab_counter);   
        newTable.append('<thead class="ui-widget-header"><tr></tr></thead>');
        alert("Header Created");
        var thead = $('thead tr', newTable);
        thead.append('<th><strong>Symbol</strong></th>');
        thead.append('<th><strong>Price</strong></th>');
        thead.append('<th><strong>Volume</strong></th>');
        thead.append('<th><strong>Buy</strong></th>');
        thead.append('<th><strong>Sell</strong></th>');
        alert("Header Created");
```

What exactly i am doing wrong over here. I am very new to jquery and still trying my best.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can create a table very easy in jquery:

```
var table = "<table class='draggable ui-widget'>" +
            "<thead><tr><th></th></tr></thead>"+
            "<tbody>"+
            "<tr><td></td></tr>"+
            "<tr><td></td></tr>"+
            "</tbody></table>";
```

Then append it to your div by `(#divid).append(table);`
This should work, also it is very easy.

Comment: @tittletipz....I have tried with this as well, but it is not working :( no class is working either. It has created a table but class is not working.

Comment: @tittletipz.....when i also add a class in <thead> its working fine but when when i place class in <table> it is not working.

Comment: @Java_NewBie :- hei try  @Yury Tarabanko's answer

Comment: @tittletip...ok i will try it. but i am confused that it is working fine in <thead> tag, but not in <table> tag.:(

Comment: this is the code.....
var newTable = "<table id='myTable'+tab_counter class='draggable ui-widget table1'>" +
      "<thead class='ui-widget-header'>"+
      "<tr><th><strong>Symbol</strong></t/h>"+
      "<th><strong>Price</strong></th>"+
      "<th><strong>Volume</strong></th>"+
      "<th><strong>Buy</strong></th>"+
      "<th><strong>Sell</strong></th></tr></thead></table>";

Comment: @tittletipz....only draggable class is not working..else every class is working fine. I have downloaded the draggable library from a website and there it specifies to add a draggable as a class.
this is the website: http://www.danvk.org/wp/dragtable/

Comment: Hm... this library dragtable.js you are using have nothing in common with jQueryUI.draggable. I think this library won't work with dinamically added tables. `if (arguments.callee.done) return;
    arguments.callee.done = true;` in init method. I do recommend you to use jQueryUI instead.

Answer (score 0):

Adding class is not enough. AFAIK you should explicitly point your element to be draggable. For example add id to your table element `<table id='draggable'...` and then make it draggable `$('#draggable').draggable();`.

By the way dom manipulations are very expensive. So it's better in terms of performance costs first create entire table html like @tittletipz pointed it out and then append it to your div.

Comment: Yury Tarabanko....basically i am also creating dynamic id's as well and i tried with this solution as well but it is not working.:( when i manually create a table and supply an id to a table. then it is working fine. but a trouble occurs when i go for a dynamic creation of a table.

Comment: As I have already said adding class `draggable` is not enough to make element draggable. http://jsfiddle.net/YV7Pf/2/. `$( "#draggable" ).draggable();` The point is not about ids.

Comment: Yury Tarabanko...thanks for your concern. I have tried $( "#draggable" ).draggable(); it drags the whole table but not the columns. but atleast it worked a little bit :). i want to drag the columns. manually it is working fine but dynamically it drags the whole table not the columns.

Comment: @Java_NewBie I see. I'd recommend you to use a grid plugin supporting columns reorder. http://datatables.net or jqgrid for example.

Comment: @Yury Tarabanko...ok i am going to try this.

Comment: @Yury Tarabanko...i wonder why it is working fine manually but not working in dynamically generated table.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically added class cannot be accessed by events normally

In your example if i have to trigger a function on click event, I cannot use

```
$('.draggable').click(function{
});
```

I should use

```
 $('.draggable').live('click', function{
    });
```

as binding to event can happen only like this. But you have not mentioned how do you want to use the class

Comment: @sathishn..i have also tried with this solution but not working...i am stuck into this :(.